# How prevent Spring boot war file load component twice in separated context?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, components, war

I have a spring boot application, packaged as a war file and deployed on tomcat server. I noticed that some component load twice in startaup:

1. when application is started
2. when ServletInitializer is started.

It caused me some problem because one of my components is EnableAsync and should do some scheduled task frequently. when it load twice in tow separated context each task is done twice and make duplicated rows in database.

Is there a way that force some component just load in single context in Spring boot? it means prevent bean to be initialized in ServletInitializer for example.

That's my SpringBootServletInitializer code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TestApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont load it twice. You are probably loading the same configuration twice or using component-scanning in both the root and child context. Also why the `ServletInitializer`? Looks like that is the thing loading the application twice...

Comment: I added my SpringBootServletInitializer code to the my question, I didnt specify component scanning or start anything twice.

Comment: This should be loading it only once, if it is loading twice you must have something else in your application (a `web.xml`?) or another initializer or bootstrapping your code (or another component).

Comment: That being said it is advisable to add additional configuration (the `@Enable*` stuff) in a separate `@Configuration` class (this also helps with sliced testing i.e. using `@WebMvcTest` for instance).

Comment: I really appreciate your advice! I found another SpringBootServletInitializer in my project, It remains of my deprecated changes and I'd forget to delete it :) you saved me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) I  found out there is an extra SpringBootServletInitializer in my code! I deleted it and Every thing is Ok now!